# dnf mentions excluded packages while they are not marked as excluded

Tags: centos, dnf

I just installed centos8. I try to install the latest version of docker-ce:

```
dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
dnf install docker-ce
```

then dnf tells me:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:19:10 ago on Fri 11 Oct 2019 09:29:33 AM 
CEST.
Error: 
 Problem: package docker-ce-3:19.03.3-3.el7.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package docker-ce-3:18.09.1-3.el7.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.4-3.1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
```

but I don't specify any exclusions. neither in `dnf.conf`; here is my whole `dnf.conf`:

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
best=True
```

I tried searching for the available `containerd.io` packages; but these "excluded" packages don't show up:

```
> dnf --showduplicates search containerd.io
Last metadata expiration check: 0:20:30 ago on Fri 11 Oct 2019 09:29:33 AM CEST.
======================================================================================= Name Exactly Matched: containerd.io =======================================================================================
containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64 : An industry-standard container runtime
containerd.io-1.2.0-1.2.beta.2.el7.x86_64 : An industry-standard container runtime
containerd.io-1.2.0-2.0.rc.0.1.el7.x86_64 : An industry-standard container runtime
containerd.io-1.2.0-2.2.rc.2.1.el7.x86_64 : An industry-standard container runtime
containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64 : An industry-standard container runtime
```

I don't really get why `dnf` is somehow finding those packages but at the same time excluding them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apparently there is a bug in `libsolv` which is causing the "exclusion" problem you're experiencing (see [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-ce-on-centos-8/81648) and [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/yum-repo-for-centos-8/81884/5)).  DNF uses libsolv which is an external dependency resolver.

You can install docker-ce with the following command:

```
dnf --disablerepo=AppStream install docker-ce
```

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the `libsolv` bug? It was my understanding that the root cause was related to docker not providing a "[modular](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modularity.html)" package. ["containerd packages are “providing” runc but are non-modular, and RHEL8 also has a runc package that is modular"](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-ce-on-centos-8/81648/21?u=gene1wood)